# Should the build directory be committed in a version controlled project?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm in the process of version controlling my project. I have commited the project source code using an src/ directory.

My question is, should I commit my build/ directory (sometimes called dist/ or bin/ depending on the application) when using version control?

Please explain why in any answer you give. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're specifically using `git push` as a distribution mechanism the general answer is no. The reason being that in most cases the build is idempotent and based on the source that's in version control, so if you need to recreate the build directory you simply re-run your build process. This will save you space in your repositories and possibly prevent platform/architecture issues depending on your language.

Answer (score 1):

No git source control is designed for text based files. Once compiled they are binary and although git will handle it. It will make your repo bloated.

Github offer a solution where you can upload a compiled version to store against a tag.