# how to remove Flutter Auto generate file which caused too much file for github to accept push

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

i am using the lateat flutter version, i notice something wide pass two days and is affecting to push to github i have try to add it to `.gitignore` but is not working.

when pushing it will `stop or hangs` at something like this `Total 1120 (delta 1120), reused 0 (delta 0)` which saying too large file..

here is the image

[image: Autho generated by flutter]

this is auto generated after upgrading to latest version...

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale
    en-NG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Answer (score 0):

is the build folder being tracked in version control? If yes, don't.

Why? see here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559061/should-the-build-directory-be-committed-in-a-version-controlled-project#:%7E:text=Unless%20you%27re%20specifically%20using,re%2Drun%20your%20build%20process.)

How to remove?

1. Save backup (just in case)
2. Delete build (will remove from git)
3. Run flutter build apk or flutter build appbundle.
4. You will be prompted whether to add the new files in git or not... Choose to not.
5. All well, then delete backup.